# How to sent angular value (id) along with repeating data-target to run a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, target

I have got the following code.

Here I need to pass the **angular js variable**, which is the **id** of repeating list.

Here the button is the deactivate button and **on-click a confirmation box** is shown. On *confirm click*, a function needs to run with the *passing id*.

*But I am not able to send id long with **data-target** & **data-toggle***

**In the code, I need to sent {{key.id}} to the confirmation box**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="key in services">
   <td>{{key.service}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">
      <button type="button" data-person="Zim" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Deactivate">Deactivate</button>
   </td>
</tr>

  <!-- Modal Deactivate Starts-->
```

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Box</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you want to Deactivate (servicename) service? </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="deactivate(1)" data-dismiss="modal">Deactivate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say u have to set a $scope variable to the `key` that was clicked, then use that variable in your modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a variable for future use like

HTML

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="key in services">
   <td>{{key.service}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">
      <button ng-click="selectedServiceId=key.id" type="button" data-person="Zim" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Deactivate">Deactivate</button>
   </td>
</tr>
<!-- Modal Deactivate Starts-->

<!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Box</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you want to Deactivate (servicename) service? </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="deactivate(selectedServiceId)" data-dismiss="modal">Deactivate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```